# Scalacheck verbosity

Tags: scala, scalacheck

Taking this example right from the User Guide of Scalacheck:

```
scala> import org.scalacheck.Prop.{forAll, BooleanOperators}

scala> val propTrivial = forAll { n: Int =>
     |  (n == 0) ==> (n == 0)
     | }

scala> propTrivial.check
! Gave up after only 4 passed tests. 500 tests were discarded.
```

I'd like to see the actual value that caused the test to fail. I have a similar test case in my project that produces a similar (useless) message.

I tried adding the verbosity option to sbt:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaCheck, "-verbosity", "5")
```

and also tried calling the property like

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaCheck, "-verbosity", "5")
```

But neither works. I cannot get any more output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, no value caused the test to fail, but ScalaCheck gave up because it could not find enough values to try. This is why it says `500 tests were discarded` - it's not a useless error message, it's just saying that the generated values did not match your `n == 0` precondition.

If you try with a test that *does* fail, it will tell you the failing test:

```
scala> forAll { n: Int => n > 0 }
res0: org.scalacheck.Prop = Prop

scala> res0.check
! Falsified after 2 passed tests.
> ARG_0: -2147483648
```

Comment: OK, I think I got it. I'm using ScalaCheck within ScalaTest, and ScalaTest must think that this is an error, when in fact it is not....